# Can't modify variable inside onClick method

Tags: java, android, onclick, android-button

So, I have created a java class to implement `onClickListener` and inside this class I have written the `onClick` public method. Outside of this method, I have created an int object and I want to modify this object inside the `onClick` method. I have researched a lot by also checking other similar **SO** questions and I have tried many things, like creating the object as a *public int*, or making it a *private int* and have another method to change it and then call this method inside onClick. However, nothing seems to work.

The code shown below has the int object created as a *private int* and named `turn`. To change it inside `onClick`, I have first created a public method named `changeTurn` that modifies it and then I call this method inside `onClick`.

```
public class TicTacToe implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button buttons[] = new Button[9];
    TextView result;

    public TicTacToe(Button[] buttonList, TextView text) {
        buttons = buttonList;
        result = text;
    }

    //public void

    private int turn = 1; // The object that needs to be modified in onCLick
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Button b = (Button) v;

        if((((Button) v).getText() != "X") && (((Button) v).getText() != "O")) {
            if(this.turn == 1) {
                b.setText("X");
                changeTurn(); // ***Should change the value of turn***
                result.setText("Turn is: " + this.turn);
            }
            if(this.turn == 2) {
                b.setText("O");
                changeTurn(); // ***Should change the value of turn***
                result.setText("Turn is: " + turn);
            }
        }
    }

    public void changeTurn() {
        if(this.turn == 1) {
            this.turn = 2;
        }
        if(this.turn == 2) {
            this.turn = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

From what I've tried, the program goes only inside the first *if* every time I click any of my 9 buttons, whose setOnClickListeners are connected to this onClick method. Also, the value of *turn* is always 1 when I print it out, which basically means that its value is not changed by changeTurn inside the onClick method.

General info on the application: I'm trying to make a tic-tac-toe game in a 3x3 grid with 9 buttons. Since there would be 2 players, I'm trying to use this *turn* integer to keep track of whose turn it is to press a button. If turn is 1, the button's text gets changed to X and if turn is 2, it changes to O. Right now, every time I press a button, it always changes to X.

I would really appreciate any help or ideas.

Comment: Hey @Klaus,can you tell me how do you setting click listener to you buttons?

Comment: The way I do that is by creating a TicTacToe object and then passing that to the setOnClickListener() on the main. So like this: 
TicTacToe tic = new TicTacToe(buttons, text);
Button one = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
one.setOnClickListener(tic);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting the turn to 2 and then immediately setting it back to 1.

```
// turn == 1
if(this.turn == 1) { // true
    this.turn = 2; // turn == 2
}
if(this.turn == 2) { // now true!
    this.turn = 1; // turn == 1
}
```

The easiest thing to do is to only enter the second block if the first is skipped, i.e.:

```
if(this.turn == 1) {
    this.turn = 2;
} else if(this.turn == 2) {
    this.turn = 1;
}
```

Alternatively, if you're expecting to expand the block with more turn numbers, use switch:

```
switch(this.turn) {
    case 1:
        this.turn = 2;
        break;
    case 2:
        this.turn = 1;
        break;
}
```

The only trouble with switch is if you forget a break statement you end up with an unpredictable mess.

Finally, a quick bit of advice: if you're trying to create a loop of numbers (1 .. n then back to 1) then you should consider the modulus operator (%) like `x = x % n + 1;`

Comment: Yeap, that's a great catch. I actually had to also do the same thing for the two other if statements, so make them if and else if. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

try use it like this

```
final private int[] turn = {0}
```

Then change code to

```
if(turn[0] == 1) {
        b.setText("X");
        turn[0]=2; // ***Should change the value of turn***
        result.setText("Turn is: " + turn);
    }
    if(turn[0] == 2) {
        b.setText("O");
        turn[0]=1; // ***Should change the value of turn***
        result.setText("Turn is: " + turn);
    }
```

Comment: I just tried it and it doesn't seem to work. When I click any of the buttons now, it doesn't change at all. I think it doesn't actually go inside any of the two _if_ statements. I also tried setting turn[0] = 1 outside the onClick method (to sort of initialize it), but it gives me an error saying "unexpected token".